# How to distinguish real mouse wheel events in Qt6?

Tags: macos, qt6

I'm trying to get zooming working so that the normal pan/pinch-zoom touchpad features work as expected, *and* scrolling a real mouse wheel zooms in/out (without any modifiers held).

Unfortunately it seems like touchpad pan gestures get converted into wheel events (there is `Qt::PanGesture` but it doesn't seem to be used). Therefore I need some way to distinguish *real* `QWheelEvent` events from touchpad ones.

The obvious thing is `QWheelEvent::device()->type()`:

```
if (event->device()->type() == QInputDevice::DeviceType::Mouse)
    // zoom
else
    // pan
```

Unfortunately the `QWheelEvents` *from my actual real physical mouse* have a `device()->type()` of `DeviceType::TouchPad`.

I also tried

```
event->source() != Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized
```

But again both real and touchpad events have that set to `Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is the mouse a magic mouse, i.e. no real scroll wheel?

Comment: No it's a normal one.